# Chrome method to allow Twitter videos to play in the background?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, chromium, video-playback, twitter

One thing I hate about Twitter is that when playing a video, I can't browse away from that video or page while still having it play. Is there any setting or other method in Chromium that would enable this? (Perhaps blocking the onBlur or whatever event Twitter is capturing to stop background playback?)

Here is a tweet by Glen Greenwald for an example,

- https://twitter.com/ggreenwald/status/1090954278229995520

I'm using Chromium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution is to **unset** in the Twitter setting named 'Video Autoplay'. After which, the video may stop when minimizing Chrome (in Windows), but it won't stop when setting the focus to another tab or application.

- Click your profile picture in the top right of the Twitter web site and
  select *Settings and Privacy*.

  [image]
- Scroll down to *Content* and under *Video Tweets*, uncheck the box that says
  `Video Autoplay`.

  [image]
- Click *Save Changes*, enter your password, and then click *Save Changes* again.

  [image]

[Source](https://www.howtogeek.com/311166/how-to-stop-twitter-videos-from-autoplaying/)